# Why does frama-c yield a syntax error on this?

Tags: c, frama-c

Here's a quick test-case reduced from a much larger program that yielded a syntax error with frama-c NEON:

```
cat <<"EOF" > min.i
struct list;
typedef struct list list_t;
void list_merge(list_t *, list_t *, int (const void *, const void *));
EOF
frama-c -val min.i
```

Is frama-c restricted to some subset of c99 that I'm violating here?

Comment: You almost already have a bug report for https://bts.frama-c.com/my_view_page.php . You just need to include the observed behavior (“min.i:3:[kernel] user error: syntax error”) and the desired behavior (program accepted because “gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic min.i” accepts it).

Comment: The input program can be further reduced to `void list_merge(int(int));`. This reduced program can be rewritten to `void list_merge(int (*)(int));` (which I believe to be equivalent) in order to be accepted by Frama-C, in case that helps. I didn't even know the first form was acceptable, so I for one wouldn't blame Frama-C here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void list_merge(int(int));` is accepted by Clang and GCC,
but rejected by http://cdecl.org/

It seems to be valid syntax (relevant is the definition of abstract-declarator at 6.7.7:1 in C11):

```
abstract-declarator:
    pointer
    pointeropt direct-abstract-declarator
direct-abstract-declarator:
    ( abstract-declarator )
    direct-abstract-declaratoropt [ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
    direct-abstract-declaratoropt [ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
    direct-abstract-declaratoropt [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
    direct-abstract-declaratoropt [ * ] direct-abstract-declaratoropt ( parameter-type-listopt )
```

In other words, yes, it appears that Frama-C is restricted to the subset of non-strange abstract declarators for function parameters. It is probably a simple omission and can probably be fixed if you report it.